# Do Users assume that company logos link to the "home" page?

Tags: homepage, bootstrap, logos

I have limited space on the top navigation of my bootstrap website and among other links, I have both the company logo and home (index) link,
Both logo and index scroll to the top of the page.

I want to add another link and its going to take up space.

Can I safely get rid of the "Home" link assuming the user will click on the company logo?

Comment: Yes I use the Logo as a Link to the Home page. But you still need to have a list entry for "Home" for the people who dont (want to) use the logo as Link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Links should add navigation value

If all your "home" link does is scroll to the top of the page, there's a good chance you never needed it in the first place. Sounds like you're dealing with a one page site, in which case sections can be indicated by a running side nav. That may buy you some more header real estate.